# Dual-boot two instances of the same copy of Vista using same serial number

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, multi-boot

I have a single Vista OEM registration number which has been registered to the current hardware (single partition only), and I want to use it for two instances of dual-booted Vista...

Both Vistas will be running on the same hardware, (and obviously only one at any one time).

Will they both be recognized as genuine to Windows Update etc... ie will they both pass the Windows Genuine Advantage requirements? ..
The only difference between the hardware involved will be the partition.

Also, are there any special issues with dual (tripple?) booting two instances of Vista and also one Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Hello71.. Ubuntu as the primary, one Vista to keep seperate from the kids, and the other Vista for the kids to screw up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you install the Vista operating systems first, as the Vista installer insists on having a small partition at the beginning of your drive to house the bootloader and related files.

I've never installed two instances of Vista on a single computer.  The installer might make you put the second Vista instance on a separate partition, so prepare for that.  If the second Vista installer overwrites the BCD on the bootloader partition, you can use bcdedit.exe or EasyBCD to restore it.

After getting your Vista instances straight, then install Ubuntu, and what you want to do is setup GRUB to chainload the Vista bootloader.  I'm pretty sure 10.04 and 10.10 will detect a Vista OS and set this up automatically.

Comment: That's reassuring about the installation of at least one Vista, thanks for that... I'll wait a while to see if I get a specific anaswer to the other part about "Will the registration serial number work for both copies?" ...

Comment: Update: For anyone wondering if it worked... I haven't tried LUKS yet, but I have managed to get the Tripple-Boot working with one Vista partition fully encrypted.. Truecrypt's bootmanager uses Vista's bootmanager somehow, and that Vista bootloader works fine for all three OS'es.. so I assume that LUKS on top of that will work.. I've chosen to just encrypt his /Ubuntu home directory (for now)...and *Yes* both copies of Vista accepted validation.. (after all it is the same hardware)